# How to get the geometry type of a layer in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I need to programmatically know the geometry type (lines, polygons or points) of a layer in GeoServer. I'm trying to do this using the REST API but can't seem to find a way.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

The rest api is for administrative tasks and so is not what you want. You can use a WFS describeFeature request to get the schema of a layer.